# How to run AngularJS project with Laravel

Tags: php, html, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I want run my Angular front-end client within Laravale index.html. 
I have mange to set up and build both projects. When I open Laravel Client at port 8000 it says it can not find any of the .js files (404 error). 
I read something about **base href** to be set properly but I can not figure it out.

Any ideas ?

[image: project]

Comment: Follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@juancarlosjc/angular-inside-laravel-b155736ea84b)

Comment: thanks that work. Can you put it as a answer I be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project with Angular Cli in some directory of Laravel project and then build the frontend project and copy the “dist” files in the public directory and in Laravel routes “/” render the index.html and that's it.

For more info you can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@juancarlosjc/angular-inside-laravel-b155736ea84b). I hope it would help you.

Comment: thanks perfect solution 
took me a while to understand the last command cause it was messy with the ";". 
but it worked